# How to center my cards scrollable container in the middle in all my devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a TemplateList component, which holds a list of cards. They are displayed in the middle of a some text and a button. I want my design to look like this:

[image]

My Card template container should always start in the middle in all devices, and scroll right.

My template list looks like this:

```
            <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {templates.map((item) => (
                    <TemplateCard
                        title={item.title}
                        description={item.description}
                        img={item.imgURL}
                        classNameToAdd={styles.cardContainer}
                        key={item.id}
                        onSelectCard={() => {
                            handleSelect(item.id);
                        }}
                        onDeselectCard={() => {
                            handleDeselect(item.id);
                        }}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
```

My scroll container css:

```
.scrollContainer {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

    padding-top: 3vmin;
    padding-bottom: 5vmin;

    width: 100vw;

    /* IOS & Android */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}

.scrollContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

What I did was to add a margin-left to the first card child in order to push all the cards to the right, but it isnt centering always in the same position when testing the responsiveness.

```
.cardContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}

.cardContainer:last-child {
    margin-right: 10vw;
}

.cardContainer:first-child {
    margin-left: 37vw;
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your card have a fixed width of let's say 300px, you can calculate the margin using `calc`:

```
.cardContainer:first-child {
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 150px);
}
```

So the margin will be [50% of the viewport width] minus [half the card width]